# How can I detect nearby users that are indoors in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, indoor-positioning-system

Im trying to create an app which is assigned to all staff in my company. Platform is ios. The function of this app is to detect the nearby staff indoor and data will be populated from internal DB.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795942/indoor-positioning-on-ios-with-core-location-not-accurate?rq=1

Comment: "Indoors" is very broad. Since you can't get access to cell tower database, I would use WiFi and the network, see who is hanging off what node and where.

Answer (score 0):

Your app get the user's location using GPS and send each user's location to a central server, which would then send back map data so each user could see all the others. GPS doesn't work super well indoors though, so the other option would be low power Bluetooth, but that isn't very directional. Check out [iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use GPS,it is not Accurate in door.
You may use some indoor location

**Use Ibeacon- Based On BLE**

- There is a company called Estimote,their offer their Indoor location
  SDK

**Use WIFI based Indoor location**

You may google more details, there are a lot details about Indoor Location

Comment: Also look at RadBeacons